# Zero matrix does not print as it should c++

Tags: c++, matrix, cout, zero

I am forming a zero matrix in my code and print it to see but the output in my console. But the result it gives is not a zero matrix. The matrix come out the same before and after I fill the matrix and I cannot find out waht the problem is. Should I be changing the variable to char? Pls help. Thank you.

```
 while(netlist.good()){
    netlist >> componentName >> node1 >> node2 >> value;
    maxnode= max(node1,node2);
    n=max(n,maxnode);
}
cout<< "n is "<<n<<endl;

 double g_matrix[n][n] = {{0}};

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
         cout<<g_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
     }
     cout << "\n"<< endl;
  }
```

Comment: `double g_matrix[n][n] = {{0}}` where `n` is a variable defines a variable-length array, which is not valid in standard C++.   Unfortunately, some compilers support it as a non-standard extension, but the behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: if you must use VLAs (don't), use `memset()` to initialize.

Comment: How about `vector<vector<double> > g_matrix(n, vector<double>(n, 0.));`?

Comment: @Aziuth two indirections instead of one? possibly expensive read/write operations of blocks within the matrix? different memory layout?

Comment: @J.Doe If those are issues, get a professional wrapper class, like from the Eigen library.

Answer (score 0):

`double g_matrix[n][n] = {{0}}`
This  isn't the correct way to initialise a 2-D matrix.

Here, you are only giving the value to `(0,0)` position. You may trying looping through the array and set it accordingly.

**OR**
It is better if you use the vector's constructor as given by @Aziuth:
`std::vector<std::vector<double>> g_matrix(n, std::vector<double>(n, 0.));`

The choice is yours.

Comment: *This isn't the correct way to initialise a 2-D matrix.* – What implementation are you referring to? – *It is better [...]* – Why? (Why not?)

Comment: Hint C99 TC3 §6.7.8.3: "The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size **or an object type that is not a variable length array type**"

Comment: @J.Doe You can check why I said so by just printin an 2D matrix defined as `int arr[2][2] = {{5}};` Do you expect this to be `{{5,5},{5,5}}` ?

Comment: Trial and error are not viable methods. Also the C99 Standard says it makes a difference in initialization if it's a variable length array type. Also, you didn't mention what implementation you are using for your observations.